# Android handler/thread on Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, handler

I have to transform a class usign (new Thread).start() to a thread that would allow Activity communication (so you can e.g. sej alert.show()).

The class looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyClient implements Runnable 
{
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  public void connect() 
  {
    if (!running) 
    {
      this.running = true;
      mHandler.post(this);
      // (new Thread(this)).start();
    }
  }

  public void run() 
  {
    while (this.running) 
    {
       ...
    }
    // thread ended
}
```

I've made this working but it stopped. From now on I have a black screen and I get

```
Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{...}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I can help you with connecting to a server, reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask. It was designed exactly to make interaction with the UI-thread easier than Threads and Handlers. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: sure... but how to transform a runnable class

Comment: @xpepermint: Read this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html Just reimplement your class as AsyncTask

Comment: The class extends from a XY library where there are pure Java code.

Comment: Could you explain that more, by updating the question? I think it will give you more relevant answers.

Comment: check this class https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/net/tootallnate/websocket/WebSocketClient.java...

Comment: I think you should update your question with the above link, and show the code you use that involves an activity. It will increase your chances of a useful answer